# How to reset id after deleting table using Linq in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to reset the id after delete all data in table using Linq in asp.net mvc

this the code of delete method :

```
foreach (var entity in context.LigneCde)
         context.LigneCde.Remove(entity);
         context.SaveChanges();
```

When I used

```
context.ExecuteStoreCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('BibContents',RESEED,1);");
```

It didn't work .

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to refresh your DBContext so it knows that the identity seed has been reset.

Try something along the lines of

```
dbContext.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, dbContext.Context.LigneCode);
```

Comment: OK, and what does Visual Studio tell you when you hover over the method? It may be you're missing a using reference, but without knowing what VS is complaining about it's hard to help.

Comment: VS tell me that ApplicationDbSet havn't a definition for ExecuteStoreCommand , I tried to use  context.LigneCde.SqlQuery("DBCC CHECKIDENT('LigneCommandeT',RESEED,0);"); but the id didn't reset to zero

Comment: Hmmmmm... I can't see your project, so I'm guessing, but you might have an issue with db context vs object context. ExecuteStoreCommand runs against and object context, not DB, but you ought to be able to get the object context something like this...

    var context = new YourDbContext();
    var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;
    var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
    objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('BibContents',RESEED,1);");

Comment: Note that even if you get the context to run the reset you may still need to refresh it to get the latest state (see original answer).